# How to have a batch file create another batch file

Tags: batch-file

I'm want to make my main batch file create another batch file. my main one is in a flash drive, i want it to make another batch file to eject it
having it eject the main is easy, my problem is having the main create a brand new batch and dictate which commands go in it

Comment: `echo echo "helloworld" > newbatch.bat`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create new batch file from batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28780159/create-new-batch-file-from-batch-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need multiple lines, you can use:

```
cat > newBashFile.sh << EOF
echo "first line"
echo "second line"
# multiple more commands, as long as they don't contain the string EOF
EOF
```

Another solution would be:

```
echo -e "first command\nsecond command\n..." > bashFile.sh
```

Comment: This is a Windows batch script question, not a *nix shell question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo. content > newfile.bat
```

Comment: is their a way to make it run as soon as you make it??

Comment: Yes, You can add `start myProgram.bat param1` after creating the file. **param1** are parameters optional.