# Create new batch file from batch file

Tags: batch-file

Is it possible to create a new batch file from an existing? For example in Java, C++ pretty much any other language I can run one .exe and create a different .exe with separate code. Is this possible to do in batch files?

Let's say I want test.bat to be this

```
echo hello hello
```

and I want it to create another .bat file called test2.bat which will contain this:

```
echo hi hi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [echo](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772462%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) and redirect the output to a batch file:

- test.bat

  ```
  @echo off
  @echo hello hello
  @echo echo hi hi > test2.bat
  @echo echo append something >> test2.bat
  ```

One `>` to create/overwrite any file that already exists; two `>` characters to append to the file.

Comment: I have one issue. I'm trying to write this to the second batch file `set /A seconds="%minutes%*60"` and it won't write it. How can I write variables? NVM %% escapes the % character.