# Create a Batch File Inside Another

Tags: batch-file

I want to create a batch file that can create a new Batch file that does a different task. In other words, create a .bat file, that when it opens, it creates another batch file with coding in it that carries out another task, and then runs it. It it even Possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27608418/2152082) or [that](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28780159/2152082)

Answer (score 0):

of course

```
@echo off
echo @echo off > 2.bat
echo echo 2nd >> 2.bat
call 2.bat
del 2.bat
```